# adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() position inside activity code

Tags: android, android-listview

In my activity (list view) with external adapter, I would need to refresh the data when the user goes back to the activity from another activity:

This is my current code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Empresas_MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables

     private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombreCategoria";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "idCategoria";
        private String name = "Categoria";
        private String id = "id";
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    Empresas_ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String VALORACIONEMPRESA = "valoracionEmpresa";
    static String NOMBREEMPRESA = "nombreEmpresa";
    static String DIRECCIONEMPRESA = "direccionEmpresa";
    static String STRIMAGEN = "strImagen";
    static String DESCRIPCIONEMPRESA = "descripcionEmpresa";
    static String TELEFONOEMPRESA = "telefonoEmpresa";
    static String FACEBOOKEMPRESA = "facebookEmpresa";
    static String EMAILEMPRESA = "emailEmpresa";
    static String TEXTOOFERTA = "textoOferta";
    static String HORARIOEMPRESA = "horarioEmpresa";
    static String LATITUDEMPRESA = "latitudEmpresa";
    static String LONGITUDEMPRESA = "longitudEmpresa";
    static String IDEMPRESA = "idEmpresa";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("MVASCO", "context is null!");
         // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();
     // JSON node keys


        // Get JSON values from previous intent
       name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
       id = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
        this.setTitle(name);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.empresas_listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Empresas_MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Vive Gran Canaria");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(name);
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://xxxxxx/android_ofertaslist_todas.php?id="+id);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Categorias");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("valoracionEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("valoracionEmpresa"));
                    map.put("nombreEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("nombreEmpresa"));
                    map.put("direccionEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("direccionEmpresa"));
                    map.put("strImagen", jsonobject.getString("strImagen"));
                    map.put("descripcionEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("descripcionEmpresa"));
                    map.put("telefonoEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("telefonoEmpresa"));
                    map.put("emailEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("emailEmpresa"));
                    map.put("textoOferta", jsonobject.getString("textoOferta"));
                    map.put("horarioEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("horarioEmpresa"));
                    map.put("facebookEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("facebookEmpresa"));
                    map.put("latitudEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("latitudEmpresa"));
                    map.put("longitudEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("longitudEmpresa"));
                    map.put("idEmpresa", jsonobject.getString("idEmpresa"));


                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new Empresas_ListViewAdapter(Empresas_MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

I have put the call to adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() inside the postOnExecute method, but the values are not updated when coming back from another activity where some of the values may have changed. Where or how should I use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Thank you.

Comment: you can update data in `onRestart()` or `onResume()` method and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in that

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, i have included onResume() method, but the app shows an exception:  protected void onResume()
 {
    super.onResume();

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

Comment: can you post logcat error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use either `onResume`. both functions are called on back pressed and when the activity starts for the first time.

so you should move the following:

```
new DownloadJSON().execute();
```

to

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}
```

you don't need to include `notifyDataSetChanged()` for this situation. I hope it helps you out

Comment: `onRestart` not called for the first time

Comment: ya sorry.. fixed it glad I could help

Comment: @Coderji there is now another minor issue, at first run, the process Dialog is shown, disappear and shown again, and stays until I press on  the view. When coming back from the other activity it is shown as usual, and disappears as usual.

Comment: did you remove the `new DownloadJSON` from onCreate?

Comment: that was, sorry, I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
 adapter = new Empresas_ListViewAdapter(Empresas_MainActivity.this, arraylist);
```

here you have to notify your adapter regarding data changes.

```
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // first you have to  notify adapter then Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

rest of your code is fine according to me.